# How to find file without extension

Tags: java, file

I have some uuid of file without extension

```
String uuid = "507f23e3-7634-42b6-8bef-df3eb87a595b"
```

How to find file which has this uuid and custom extension

Comment: Please elaborate. Where do you want to "find" this file? Do you know which folder it's in? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: yes I know folder and uuid of this file

Comment: You have asked (1) 'without extension' and (2) 'custom extension'. Which is it? And if you 'know the folder and UUID' what exactly is the problem? What's the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser();
  File dir = new File("directoryOfFile");
  final String uuid = "507f23e3-7634-42b6-8bef-df3eb87a595b";
  dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
     @Override
     public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
     {
        // checks for a filename consisting of uuid with a custom extension
        return name.startsWith(uuid + ".");
     }
  });
}
```

This will of course also match files that looks like this:

```
507f23e3-7634-42b6-8bef-df3eb87a595b.abc.def
```

In this case "abc" is not part of the extension, so, to avoid this (if you so desire), you can replace the `startsWith` line with:

```
return name.startsWith(uuid + ".") && name.lastIndexOf(".") == uuid.length();
```

The above just checks that the last dot is at the end of the `uuid`.